# Hello friends, I want to separate a few emails to see which ones have been created and which ones have not been created yet

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, request

see this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

list1 = []
for i in range(0, 1000):
    user = "haji1" + str(i) + "7"
    if len(user) == 7:
        user = user[:5] + "00" + user[5:]
    elif len(user) == 8:
        user = user[:5] + "0" + user[5:]
    list1.append(user + "@gmail.come")
req = requests.get(
    "https://accounts.google.com/signin/v2/identifier?hl\
    =en&continue=https%\3A%\2F%\2Fmail.google.com%\2Fmail&servi\
        ce=mail&flowName=GlifWebSignIn&flowEntry=AddSession"
)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req, "html.parser")
print(soup)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/MR/Desktop/tekrar1.py", line 14, in <module>
    soup=BeautifulSoup(req,'html.parser')
  File "C:\Users\MR\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\bs4\__init__.py", line 287, in __init__
    elif len(markup) <= 256 and (
TypeError: object of type 'Response' has no len()
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what your code should do in the end (and remember that automated requests are a surefire way to get yourself blocked from Google), but you're simply missing the access to the response's text:

```
resp = requests.get("https://accounts.google.com/signin/v2/identifier...")
resp.raise_for_status()  # raise an exception if there was an error
soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.text, "html.parser")  # see "resp.text"
print(soup)
```

Comment: Thank you my friend. I have an email that I only know some of its characters I want to see what that email is My information: gmail:haji1****7@gmail.com